# Save two values as one in a database (SQL)

Tags: java, sql

I want to save two values as one in a database how can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
      try{
               String v = "Voila";
               String c = "Magic";
               String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lemon"; 
               Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"r","s"); 
               Statement st = conn.createStatement();
               st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO rtype set RType = '" + v + "'"); // how can I add 'c' in the same column?
               conn.close();        


            } 
           catch (Exception e) { 
               System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter some values");
               System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
          }
```

As you can see, I have two strings that I should combine as one then save in a database.

The column should have "Voila Magic" if successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate them at the Java level before the insert:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO rtype set RType = '" + v + " " + c + "'");
// Here ----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

If either `v` or `c` comes from an end user, beware that your code is [wide open to SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/); here's a humorous, but serious, illustration of them:

[image]

Even if they don't, if either could contain `'`, your statement would end up being invalid SQL and failing. Use `PreparedStatement` and parameter placeholders instead:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO rtype set RType = ?");
ps.setString(1, v + " " + c);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with modification to your code:

```
try{
           String v = "Voila";
           String c = "Magic";
           String rType = v + " " + c;
           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lemon"; 
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"r","s"); 
           Statement st = conn.createStatement();
           st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO rtype set RType = '" + rType + "'"); // how can I add 'c' in the same column?
           conn.close();        


        } 
       catch (Exception e) { 
           System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter some values");
           System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a separator while concatenate the two strings by using any specific character like #, ^ etc., (space likely to occur more common in the strings and avoiding space as a separator by any of the two methods suggested by Crowder.

So that you can split the values you fetch it back from the database in order to show those 2 values in 2 separate fields (probably 2 text fields on a web page) basing on you requirement.